# Which is the process that occurs when the layout system is invoked in WPF?

Tags: wpf

Each time that a child UIElement changes its position, it has the potential to trigger a new pass by the layout system.

Which is the process that occurs when the layout system is invoked in WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the paragraph [The Layout System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx#LayoutSystem_Overview) on MSDN:

> 1. A child UIElement begins the layout process by first having its core properties measured.
> 2. Sizing properties defined on FrameworkElement are evaluated, such as Width, Height, and Margin.
> 3. Panel -specific logic is applied, such as Dock direction or stacking Orientation.
> 4. Content is arranged after all children have been measured.
> 5. The Children collection is drawn on the screen.
> 6. The process is invoked again if additional Children are added to the collection, a LayoutTransform is applied, or the
>      UpdateLayout method is called.

Comment: Please never forget to mention the source of your knowldge.